# Why can I compile and install Nokogiri, but can't require it, in Windows 7?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to use Nokogiri on Windows 7 on a 64-bit PC using 64-bit versions of Windows, Ruby 2.0.0, and DevKit. I just installed the xml2/xslt/iconv/zlib libs from ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/64bit/ and moved `include/libxml2/libxml` into `include/libxml`; I suppose I could have just adjusted `--with-xml2-include`), and then installed Nokogiri. It seemed to build the native extension fine.

When I try to require Nokogiri I get:

```
C:/Users/echristopherson/Development/Ruby/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in
`require':LoadError: 126: The specified module could not be found.   -
C:/Users/echristopherson/Development/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
```

When I check the file type:

```
file C:/Users/echristopherson/Development/Ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.5.9/lib/nokogiri/nokogiri.so
```

It outputs:

```
PE32+ executable for MS Windows (DLL) (console) Mono /.Net assembly.
```

What am I doing wrong? I get the same results with `gem install --pre nokogiri ...`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By your output I see you are using Ruby 2.0.0. Nokogiri doesn't have yet support for Ruby 2.0.0 on Windows x64; according to [Nokogiri issue 864](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/864), this is due to [rake-compiler's current inability (as of May 7, 2013) to target the x64-mingw32 platform](https://github.com/luislavena/rake-compiler/pull/74).

Comment: I'm having trouble getting my app to get through a 'bundle install' on Windows 7 with Ruby 2.0.0-p247 from the installer. It is giving me trouble with nokogiri and saying it can't find libxml. Is that the problem here? Should I drop back to 1.9.x?

Comment: @B5Fan74 is your windows 7 32 or 64 bits?